# Override yml configuration in spring-boot with command line arguments

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that is configured with a yml file. Is it possible to override these properties when executing the jar? For example let say I have the input variable in yml file set to user1 and I want to execute the jar with user2. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
java -jar --input=user2
```

Comment: According to the docs, it is possible http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I overrride my tomcat port defined in the application.yml file as server:  port: ${port:8080} using --server.port=8090

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate [answer by cLyric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502215/365237), you can do this:

```
java -jar yourapp.jar --input=user2
```

Or if you want to provide using json, you can do

```
java -jar yourapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"input":"user2"}'
```

Or if you're in unix/linux,

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"input":"user2"}' java -jar yourapp.jar
```

Comment: In my project, it's not work on "java -jar app.jar --input=user2" but work well with "java  -Dinput=user2 -jar app.jar". But with the second command can't override configuration in application.properties

Comment: @free斩 the second command is different, not related to spring boot. You should probably open another question if the standard `--input` style is for some reason not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244380/override-yml-configuration-in-spring-boot-with-command-line-arguments-not-work

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

> java -Dspring.profiles.active=test-environment -jar config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

If we see below syntax, it tells options should be included between **java** and **-jar**. Also, **options** are listed below as well.

Reason why this command works. Also, it takes the parameters instead of the application.yml configuration.

*C:\Users\joy> java -?*

*Usage:* **java** *[-options]* **-jar** *jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)*
where **options** ***include***:

```
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server. 
 -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
 -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
               A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
               and ZIP archives to search for class files.
 **-D<name>=<value>
               set a system property**
```

*Note: Operating system is windows*

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.