# Override yml configuration in spring-boot with command line arguments not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, command, overriding

I have a spring-boot application. I want to override some properties which was configuration in application.yml when executing the jar.

My code like this:

```
@Service
public class CommandService {

    @Value("${name:defaultName}")
    private String name;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

And the Application.java is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CommandService commandService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        commandService.print();
    }
}
```

The application.yml

> name: nameInApplication

when I excute the command like that:

> java -jar app.jar --name=nameInCommand

It's not work

The Second command also not work:

> java -Dname=nameInCommand2 -jar app.jar

But if the application.yml not have config the name, the second command will work well and the first command also not work any way.

Comment: Do you pass command line arguments when starting application with `SpringApplication.run()`?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything when start appliction with SpringApplication.run()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a few months old, but I'm going to answer it because I just ran into this issue and found your question via google and Ivan's comment jogged my memory. Since he did not elaborate and I'm not sure if you solved your issue (you probably have by now), you are going to want to change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

That simple. The arguments before were never going anywhere when they got passed in thus not overriding your application.yml property. So just in case you haven't figured it out or if someone stumbled upon this question like I did, that is what Ivan meant by

> do you pass command line arguments when starting
>   `SpringApplication.run(...)`?